# Randomly subsampling a dataframe without replacements in a specific column with R

Tags: r, dataframe, sampling

I have a dataframe with this structure:

```
> df
factor  y  x
1       2  0
1       3  0
1       1  0
1       2  0
2       3  0
2       1  0
2       3  1
3       4  1
3       3  1 
3       6  3
3       5  2
4       4  1
4       7  8
4       2  1
2       5  3
```

In the actual dataset, I have 200 rows and different variables: several continuous variables and a factor variable with 70 levels with up to 4 observations each.

I would like to randomly subsample my entire dataframe into 4 groups of equal size without replacements within each group exclusively in the factor variable. In other words, I would like to have each level of the factor variable occurring not more than once per group.

I've tried different solutions.
For instance, I tried by sampling the "factor" variable into four groups without replacements as follows:

```
factor1 <- as.character(df$factor)

set.seed(123)
group1 <- sample(factor, 35,replace = FALSE) 

factor2 <- setdiff(factor1, group1) 
group2 <- sample(factor2, 35,replace = FALSE) 

# and the same for "group3" and "group4"
```

but then I don't know how to associate the group vectors (group1, group2, etc.) to the other variables in my df ('x' and 'y').

I've also tried with:

```
group1 <- sample_n(df, 35, replace = FALSE)
```

but this solution fails as well since my dataframe doesn't include duplicated rows. The only duplicated values are in the factor variable.

Finally, I tried to use the solution proposed in reply to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174721/create-random-subsets-in-r-without-duplicates), adapted to my case:

```
random.groups <- function(n.items = 200L, n.groups = 4L,
                          factor = rep(1L, n.items)) {

  splitted.items  <- split(seq.int(n.items), factor)

  shuffled <- lapply(splitted.items, sample)

  1L + (order(unlist(shuffled)) %% n.groups)
}

df$groups <- random.groups(nrow(df), n.groups = 4)
```

However, the resulting 4 groups include duplicated values for the factor variable, so something is not working properly.

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion to solve this problem!

Comment: use dplyr() : new_df <- df%>% group_by(factor) %>% sample_n(35). Please provide sample output to understand more in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to group by factor, create a variable of factro's length, arrange by size and length. At the end, you assign a group to each first, second, third and fourth row. You can then filter out using this variable.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(factor = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,2),
                 x = floor(runif(15, min=0, max=20)),
                 y = floor(runif(15, min=211, max=305)))
df <- df %>% group_by(factor) %>% mutate(size = length(factor)) %>% arrange(desc(size), factor) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%  mutate(group = ifelse(row_number() %% 4 == 1, "A",
                                       ifelse(row_number() %% 4 == 2, "B",
                                              ifelse(row_number() %% 4 == 3, "C", "D"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution demonstrated with a slightly larger dataset:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- setorder(data.table(factor = sample(10, 44, TRUE), x = runif(44), y = runif(44)), factor)
numGroups <- 4L
maxFactor <- max(dt$factor)
dt2 <- setorder(
  setorder(
    dt[sample(.N, .N)], # randomly reorder the data
    factor              # sort by factor
  )[, temp := cumsum(.I > 0), by = factor] # create a column to keep a running count of the occurrence of each factor
  [temp <= numGroups]                      # remove rows that can't go in a group due to factor exclusion
  [sample(.N, .N) <= (.N %/% numGroups)*numGroups] # randomly remove excess rows (keep the group sizes equal)
  [, temp := sample(10, 10)[factor]]               # randomly reorder factor groups
  [, grp := c(rep(1:numGroups, .N/numGroups))],    # assign each row a group: row 1 -> group 1, row 2 -> group 2 ... 5 -> 1, 6 -> 2, etc.
  grp # sort by group for table readability
)[, temp := NULL] # remove the temporary column
```

The resulting `data.table` will have `numGroups` groups as indicated by the `grp` column. Each group will have same number of rows. The number of rows in each group will be the maximum possible in order to meet the no duplicate factor constraint. For a smaller sample, take a subsample of `dt2` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289182/sample-random-rows-within-each-group-in-a-data-table)).